# Prove H is in the center Z(G)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Exercise from Artin's 2nd edition of Algebra.

Let $H$ be a normal subroup of prime order $p$ in a finite group $G$. Suppose that $p$ is the smallest prime that divides the order of $G$. Prove that $H$ is in the center $Z(G)$.

My attempt:
 Choose any $e\neq h \in H$, since $h$ is normal, the conjugacy class including $h$ lies in $H$, so this class has size less than $p$. The only positive integer less than $p$ which divides $|G|$ is one. So the class containing $h$ has size one, and $h \in Z(G)$.

Correct?

Comment: Correct. And it's actually a really nice way to show this. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474276/normal-subgroup-of-prime-order-in-the-center) is a different proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. Alternatively stated: $H$ is normal so it is a union of conjugacy classes; all those ccls have order dividing $G$, and hence have size either $1$ or bigger than $p$ (by definition of $p$ as the smallest prime dividing $|G|$). Therefore it is a union of size-1 ccls.